# Getting a log/stack trace from an Error Id with basic support

Tags: support, gack

I have a client who only has "basic" support.  Earlier today, we started getting error messages from some time based workflows actions.

I created an support case asking if they could send us the error log or stack-trace for the given Error Id.  I agent said that because they are on the "basic" support tier he could not give me that information.

There solution was to deactivate the trigger.  We are using a trigger handler pattern to control order of execution, so this would literally mean we'd have to deactivate all of our processes on that object.

Is this standard procedure for basic support?  Seems absurd that you'd have to pay extra for something as fundamental as getting to see your own error logs.

Comment: can you copy the PROD org into a sandbox and try to isolate the issue?  If it makes you feel any better, we have Premier Support and when I asked for the gack logs, Support never delivered on it until long after I had self-diagnosed the issue via selective reduction

Comment: Yes, this is their standard procedure. I have a client who had a bug in their organization and they did nothing because of the basic support level (a class was scheduled, and executed with an error, but the record that indicates the schedule wasn't deleted and could not be deleted manually). At the end, I was lucky because the error happened in sandbox, not in production, so I deleted the sandbox and recreated it.

Comment: What did the Error Id look like? Likely it was a [GACK](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html) code.

Comment: @DanielBallinger ya, it was a GACK.  Luckily, with a bit of pain,  I was able to reproduce the issue in production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think they will give out the internal stack trace for a GACK even if you have Premier support. It would probably show too much of the internals of how Salesforce works.

Is there somewhere that outlines what you get with basic support?

---

[image]

I see in the [Partner-Basic-Support PDF](http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/misc/Partner-Basic-Support-Master.pdf) that they will troubleshoot a Salesforce error message that corresponds to a known bug. To me that sounds like a Tier 1 support person will lookup the GACK ID against a known issue and then give you a link to the known issue. I've long been an advocate that we could do this ourselves if the information was exposed. See Idea [Provide a public reference of GACK general stack trace identifiers](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DklZAAS)

Beyond that the support case would probably need to be escalated to a higher Tier of support or R&D. These higher support levels are better suited to going from a GACK and creating a new known issue.

Comment: I can 100% confirm that support has definitely given me stack traces in the past.  For our client who have premiere support it seems to be a trivial request.